# Programatically install a certificate to Mozilla Firefox without certutil.exe

Tags: c#, firefox, certificate, certutil

How to programatically install a certificate to Mozilla Firefox without certutil.exe? I don't want to use NSS library for Firefox. What are the alternatives of certutil? Any suggestions?